# Select2 and django_filters not querying foreign keys

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2, django-filters

I'm using django_filters for an advanced search and select2Widget to display the options of a foreign key field.

The proper values load but whenever I submit the form I get an error message: *Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available* choices.

The error might seem pretty obvious but I can't find out how to solve it. Any suggestions?

**filters.py**

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    b = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=ModelA.objects.values_list('b__name', flat=True)
        widget=Select2Widget()
    )

class Meta:
    model = ModelA
    fields = ('b',)
```

**models.py**

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey('ModelB', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Is it just a typo or do you have `model = A` in `MyFilter.Meta` ? Shouldn't it be `model = ModelA`?

Comment: @Ralf it was a typo. Thanks. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: The only way to debug is: 1) check your HTML source to see if the values (not the visible labels) for each option are correctly set and whether the `<select>` field is correctly named. 2) set a breakpoint or print in your view the `request.POST` data to check what is being submitted.

Comment: Shouldn't your queryset in the filter be `ModelB.objects.all()`? Since you want to be presented with a choice of B's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS user @dirkgroten pointed out in a comment to the question, the following line looks strange:

```
queryset=ModelA.objects.values_list('b__name', flat=True)
```

This way the widget has no way of knowing the `pk` of each element of the list (since it only return the names). That might couse that the view cannot save a selected `ModelB` instance, since it does not know the selected `pk`.

Ah, you might also want to use `ModelB` instead of `ModelA`

Try changing it to something like this

```
queryset=ModelB.objects.values('pk', 'b__name')
```

or even this

```
queryset=ModelB.objects.all()
```

and let us know if that works.

Comment: Changing it to ModelB instead of ModelA solved it. Thank you, you're awesome!